# React container in docker compose doesn not pick up build arg

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a repo containing a frontend react app and a backend python api server. But I cannot seem to get the url of the backend service and pass to my react app.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://backend:80
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:3000

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    ....
```

My `Dockerfile` in the `frontend` folder for React:

```
FROM node:20
WORKDIR /app

ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL

COPY ./package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN npm i
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then in my React NextJS app, `process.env` is an empty object.

Anything I'm missing? Is this the best approach to pass the backend url to React?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the "best approach" but it works.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://backend:80
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:3000

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

`index.js` In the `frontend` folder. This is doing a couple of things: (1) prints the contents of the `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL` environment variable and (2) pulling a response from the backend service.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch('http://backend:80');
  const pageContent = await res.text();
  return { props: { pageContent } };
}

function HomePage({ pageContent }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to My Next.js App</h1>
      {/* Print value of the NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL environment variable. */}
      <p>API URL: {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL}</p>
      <hr></hr>
      {/* Include content from backend. */}
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: pageContent }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

The `Dockerfile` in `backend/` is the same as provided in the question.

The `Dockerfile` in `backend/` is super simple, just for illustration.

```
FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Opening http://127.0.0.1:80/ retrieves the page from the `frontend` service. This, in turn, pulls the response from the `backend` service. It also prints the value of `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL` from `process.end`.

[image]